# Correct settings for C++ to recognize compiler options?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code

In VS Code I have a define identifier that is not found. The variable is eventually passed to the compiler as a flag `-DENABLE_LOGS_PREVIEW` and found in `./cmake-build-debug/build.ninja`. I build with CMake and Ninja directly from the command line.

```cpp
#ifdef ENABLE_LOGS_PREVIEW
std::cout << "Hello world" << std::endl;
#endif
std::cout << "Goodbye world" << std::endl;
```

Correctly prints, though VS Code greys out `std::cout << "Hello world" << std::endl;`

```
Hello world
Goodbye world
```

I'm struggling to get the correct `c_cpp_properties.json` to work with my workflow. How do I get the above define to be recognized?

Comment: Try to generate `compile_commands.json`, with CMake, the flags from our should be picked up automatically.

Comment: That worked, I had not known about `compile_commands.json`. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

The answer here was to have CMake to generate a [compile_commands.json](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS.html) and add it to the VS Code `c_cpp_properties.json` like so:

```
"compileCommands": "${workspaceFolder}/cmake-build-debug/compile_commands.json"
```